# How to update the $scope variable values with the new Values I'm getting from the Database?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have been setting the response values every time I hit the `web-service` to a `$scope` variable on click of a button but the `$scope` variable is not getting updated with the new values I have to Click the button twice so that the `$scope` variables get updated. also I have checked, each time I hit the button the `web-service` is properly getting called.

controller.js

```
$scope.getDetails = function() {
  services.getSomeDetails($scope.id).then(function(response) {

            $scope.details= response.data;

  }
}
```

view.html

```
 <a ng-click="getDetails();">Click me!</a>
```

Comment: You should add code to the question!

Comment: okay i adeed, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$scope.$apply()` after your scope Variable.

```
  services.getSomeDetails($scope.id).then(function(response) {

        $scope.details= response.data;

        $scope.$apply();

   }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using jquery click event, it will not trigger digest circle of angular. Use [ng-click](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick) directive or add `$scope.$digest()` or `$scope.$apply()` after update scope variable

```
services.getSomeDetails($scope.id).then(function(response) {

            $scope.details= response.data;
            $scope.$apply()

  }
```